# DWARF info seem to be wrong for DW_AT_high_pc with gcc 4.8.2

Tags: c, gcc, objdump, dwarf

As a newbie to  DWARF, I tried the code presented [in this page](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/07/how-debuggers-work-part-3-debugging-information/) (code is [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/files/prog_code/articles_code/debugger/dwarf_get_func_addr.c)) but when I launch it I get:

```
$> ./dwarf_get_func_addr tracedprog
DW_TAG_subprogram: 'do_stuff'
abort() in libdwarf. No error argument, no handler.
zsh: abort (core dumped)  ./dwarf_get_func_addr tracedprog
```

After a debugging session, the problem appears to come from line 78:

```
    else if (attrcode == DW_AT_high_pc)
        dwarf_formaddr(attrs[i], &highpc, 0);
```

The problem is, the `form` of `attrs[i]` shows `attrs[i]` is not an address (it is set to 7 instead of 1).
Exploring `tracedprog` with `objdump` it gives, for `do_stuff` function:

```
<1><73>: Numéro d'abréviation: 4 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
    <74>   DW_AT_external    : 1
    <74>   DW_AT_name        : (chaîne indirecte, décalage: 0x55): do_stuff
    <78>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <79>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 4
    <7a>   DW_AT_prototyped  : 1
    <7a>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x400500
    <82>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0x3f
    <8a>   DW_AT_frame_base  : 1 bloc d'octets: 9c      (DW_OP_call_frame_cfa)
    <8c>   DW_AT_GNU_all_tail_call_sites: 1
    <8c>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0xb9>
```

In this output, `DW_AT_high_pc` doesn't seem correct to me as it is only two octets long.

For your reference, I compiled `tracedprog` with:

```
$> gcc -g tracedprog2.c -o tracedprog
```

**Edit** it seems to be a `gcc` issue as there is no issue on another machine. I am using `gcc 4.8.2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue. Starting from `gcc 4.8`, default **DWARF** version is 4. To make my program work, I had to compile `tracedprog` with `-gdwarf-2` flag.

Answer (score 4):

To use `DW_AT_high_pc` with libdwarf on a binary compiled by gcc >= 4.8 without overriding the default DWARF version one has to check the form of the attribute before extracting the value.

Depending on the version of the DWARF information, the `DW_AT_high_pc` attribute can be either a `DW_FORM_addr` form or a `DW_FORM_data8` form. Each form has its own extracting function.

Here is an example of how to check the form of the an attribute:

```
void print_attribute(Dwarf_Attribute a)
{
    Dwarf_Half form;
    Dwarf_Error err;
    Dwarf_Half attrcode;
    unsigned int offset = 0;
    Dwarf_Addr addr;

    dwarf_whatform(a, &form, &err);

    switch(form)
    {
    case DW_FORM_addr:
        dwarf_formaddr(a, &addr, &err);
        printf("DW_FORM_addr: 0x%08llx\n", addr);
        break;
    case DW_FORM_data8:
        dwarf_formudata(a, &offset , &err);
        printf("DW_FORM_data8: 0x%08llx\n", offset);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For reference, in DWARF 4, DW_AT_high_pc can be of class constant. In this case, the value is an offset from the low_pc. The referenced code does not handle this.